# Add webmasters and networkengineering to our "on-topic" help page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

From https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic:

```
 We also have sister sites that cover specific topics in more detail:

 Stack Overflow for Programming
 Super User for general Networking, Hardware, and Technology
 Unix & Linux for general Unix/Linux usage
 DBA for Advanced Database topics
 IT Security for Advanced Security (implementation, theory, white hat)
```

Can the mighty SE powers please add webmasters.SE and networkengineering.SE (beta) to the list?

Edit: Right, networkengineering being in beta not being a suitable target, so drop that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webmasters has been added to this list. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Probably not until NetworkEngineering graduates out of beta.

I'm still largely unconvinced whether it "deserves" to be a separate site.

Webmasters OTOH, probably wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The serverfault moderators get to decide whether a site approved via Area51 gets to live or not? This is quite new to me.

Comment: One has to be the one to decide in order to have an opinion? This is quite new to me.

Comment: One has to be the one to have to be the one to decide to have an opinion? This is quite new to me.

Comment: You guys are weird, but the point that Tom was making @pauska is that beta sites aren't really mentioned on graduated sites. That way, if they fail, SE doesn't have to track down all of the references to the dead site.

Comment: @JennyD You're extremely narrow-sighted if you didn't understand why I reacted to a elected mod expressing his opinion on a user-voted site in a an answer to a specific request about the site on a meta thread. But ok, whatever floats your boat :-)

Comment: @MDMarra I have no problem accepting that. It's just the snark between that doesn't belong here, especially not from a moderator.

Comment: I genuinely don't know whether NE.se adds more to the network than it takes away from SF.

Comment: @Pauska If you react to something you dislike with snark, don't be surprised if your snark is met with more snark. Had you originally written the thing about "elected mod expressing...", I probably would not have even commented.

Comment: I didn't realise that I wasn't allowed an opinion any more.

Comment: Can we just all hold hands and sing Kumbaya?