# Should NetworkEngineering be added to the migration close reason?

Tags: feature-request

While I get there are already plenty to choose from, I'm curious what the percentage of each of those migration options actually occur in a month or year (but have no idea how to compose such a data query).

Although I'm not around daily anymore I see quite a few questions specific to networking.  Questions focused around switching, hardware firewalls, hardware routers.

Should these questions that focus around networking topics and aren't simply an extension of a server question exist on SF or should they be migrated to NetworkEngineering?

Or as an alternative, add them to the Help section per this Meta question: [Add webmasters and networkengineering to our "on-topic" help page](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5702/add-webmasters-and-networkengineering-to-our-on-topic-help-page)

Answer (score 6):

The problem with adding this  as a migration target is that we would need to remove others, as the SE team strictly limits the number of targets and (without having hard numbers at hand) I don't believe that we get more networking questions then those that would be migrated to one of the present selections (SO, SU, DBA, U&L).

If you see a good(!) network engineering question, just flag for migration.

Adding it to the help page is a good idea though, and I've just done so.

Comment: Thanks Sven...is there any way to quantify the DBA, U&L ones?  I know SO and SU would be more than NE, but I'm skeptical on the other two, especially DBA.  Maybe we can replace DBA with NE?

Comment: According to some mod-only statistic, we have migrated 9 questions to dba and one to NE in the last 90 days.

Comment: OK thanks!  I wonder if that is because the option for DBA is already there, but I digress.  I think adding it to the Help section may be good enough!